# Using Iframe to quickly authenticate user in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, saml

I am using Iframe inside one of my templates, for authentication.

**For Example:** *If a user completes a training, he has to verify his identity by authenticating with a ping identity server which will redirect to some other url depending upon the credentials added.*

Ping Identity is hosted on other domain, and app is on some other domain. I know about the cross origin issues. But i have a server in-front of our app which has same domain as the app and which calls ping identity from within. So i am using that server for authentication.

The thing is i still get CORS errors in console. What is the best way to go for such authentication, considering user experience and security as well in mind?

Comment: "But i have a server in-front of our app which has same domain as the app and which calls ping identity from within."  ---  So you're behind a reverse proxy in the same domain as the PingFed server? If so, then CORS shouldn't come into play. It's the browser that prevents cross origin resources based on domains in use and CORS configuration, so if the iFrame appears to the browser to be loading from the reverse proxy (same domain), then it should be fine - if it's NOT the reverse proxy, then it will fail.

Comment: Its not any proxy server

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. Explain how you are, or think you can use this other server... or remove it from the equation.

Comment: I can not change Ping Identity configs as its a third party server for authentication. I might have to remove it from the equation. I don't have any proxy server in front of the app which can help. I might have to open a the Ping Identity page in the same app page and redirect back to app after successful login. I wanted to avoid it, as user experience suffers due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Then just get CORS configured in PingFederate by managing the headers:
https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf80/index.shtml#concept_addingCustomHttpResponseHeaders.html

You do this by editing: /pingfederate/server/default/data/config-store/response-header-runtime-config.xml.

Use http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ to help guide you through CORS.

Comment: Thing is, I cannot make changes in that configuration, had already tried. Instead, what i am allowed to change is the redirect URL, which is what i am doing. But the question is, "What is the best way to go for such authentication, considering user experience and security as well in mind?"

Comment: IMO? Get rid of iFrames, and just do it with redirecting to identity provider requesting a specific authentication context and forcing authentication. That's the "SAML" way to do it...

Comment: Agreed, but it was the client requirement, user should not be redirected but saml fedLogin inside popup should be shown. Found a workaround to fix the above issue. Thanks anyways.